# Creating a skeleton project directory

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt, directory-structure, mkdir

I am a rookie in Python who has been working on Learn Python the Hard Way. This whole process goes well as I have a smattering knowledge on Python until I march into ex46 where I get stuck in the 'Creating the skeleton Project Directory' section. I have no idea where I should run those commands guided on this book. Following are the excerpt of this part:

> First, create the structure of your skeleton directory with these commands:
>
> ```
> $ mkdir projects     
> $ cd projects/       
> $ mkdir skeleton        
> $ cd skeleton             
> $ mkdir  bin        
> $ mkdir NAME     
> $ mkdir tests  
> $ mkdir docs
> ```

I have tried to run these commands in Windows Powershell, only to be warned that these commands can’t be recognized. I also fumbled to execute them in Pycharm, but all in vain. Could someone point out how I could get it done?

In addition, I am somewhat curious about this method because there seems to be handy way to approach this on Pycharm. Could I achieve the same goal on that?

I am using Python 2.7 and all previous exercises operate well until ex46.

Comment: This isn't a Python question... Your code works fine for me in Powershell. Wait a minute... are you literally typing in `$ mkdir projects` with the `$` sign at the beginning?!

Comment: Also, "Learn Python the Hard Way" has received a good deal of criticism for being misleading ([example](https://eev.ee/blog/2016/11/23/a-rebuttal-for-python-3/)), so you may want to reconsider your Python tutorial choices.

Comment: And by the way (even if off topic)... It's enough to just type __one statement__ instead of 8.

Comment: Please show the actual error you're getting. `mkdir` and `cd` are valid aliases in the default PowerShell setup and should be working just fine.

Comment: @Clijsters I see, thanks very much.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett thanks for your kind tip! Actually, i have also finished Beginning Python: From a Novice to a Professional and did acquire some basics. But that book was a little confusing, too. Could you warmly offer some advice on how to learn Python on my own? Sincere gratitude!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett thanks for your inspiration. I have found out the problem here: the $ sign shouldn’t be typed into the command line. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yup... the `$` is the (Linux) command prompt. On your Windows machine it's something like `C:\>`. Don't type that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because you're typing a superfluous `$` at the beginning of each command. That `$` is the (Linux) [command prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt). On your Windows machine, it's something like `C:\WINDOWS\system32>`. Don't type that.

Just type

```
mkdir projects
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That creates a folder (directory) named "projects". Then type

```
cd projects
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. That changes the current directory to that new folder you just created. And so on.

<sub>Content migrated from comments since this is what actually solved the issue.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dollar sign `$` from the statement, as this is just the symbol used as a CLI prompt not part of the statement itself.

Then type the mkdir command  and it should work e.g.

```
mkdir my_directory
```